# Frames captured from webcam, processed, and drawn on canvas appear out of order in macOS Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-canvas, html5-video, requestanimationframe

### tl;dr

See Option B for my code.
The gif under Phenomenon shows the issue.
Only happens in Safari.

### Background

I’m creating a web-based machine learning demo. The demo captures a local live webcam feed from the user, processes the image (think of something like finding a face, then running some convolutional neural nets on the image). Then, displays the results (like the face highlighted with a rectangle, and some text) to the user, like a mirror.

To get an idea, imagine something like this:
https://tastenkunst.github.io/brfv4_javascript_examples/
(This is not my app, just an example. As of now, I can’t share my actual app.)

### Goal

- Capture image from webcam.
- Run some long-running calculation on the captured image.
- Display the image (captured in step 1) and the calculation results on canvas.
- Repeat.

### Context

Safari 12.0.2 with macOS Mojave on MBP 2018 (the issue also occurs on the several older MacBooks that I’ve tried).

Initialization (to give context to the examples):

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: { width: 320, height: 240 }
});
video.srcObject = stream;
video.setAttribute("playsinline", "true");
await video.play();
```

`captureImage()` means this:

```
tempCanvasCtx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
const image = tempCanvasCtx.getImageData(0, 0, tempCanvas.width, tempCanvas.height);
```

`longCalculation()`:
Can vary in duration (per frame, and also depending on machine) from moments to .5 second. It uses TensorFlow.js, running on GPU, and some other WebGL shader calculations (independent from the canvases).

`video` is a HTMLVideoElement, and `ctx` and `tempCanvasCtx` are 2D contexts of two different canvases. The code is inside an async function.

### Trials

**Option A**

```
const loop = async () => {
    const image = captureImage();
    const result = await longCalculation(image);
    ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

My first obvious solution, which works in every major browser, except Safari. In Safari, it is indeterministic, sometimes works, and sometimes the video freezes forever, probably due to RAF execution occasionally taking a long time and jamming RAF.

**Option B**

```
const loop = async () => {
    const image = captureImage();
    const result = await longCalculation(image);
    ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);

    setTimeout(loop, 0);
};

setTimeout(loop, 0);
```

In this case, the following happens:

### Phenomenon

The resulting video shown on the canvas does not keep the sequential order of the frames. Prior frames sometimes appear later and vice versa. It jumps back and forth a few seconds duration, sometimes more.
It gives a really creepy effect, similar to the tape in the movie The ring when in one frame, the little girl stands somewhere, and in the next, somewhere totally different. If you record a wristwatch, the second hand will jump back and forth.

[image: example]

**Option C**

```
while (true) {
    const image = captureImage();
    const result = await longCalculation(image);
    ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
}
```

I’m not sure if B and C are any different, but I included it for transparency.

I thought what I ask for should be simple… Capture a frame, and simply wait until it’s processed and displayed, before capture and process the next frame. I can’t see where things go wrong.

I’ve already tried:

- Increasing wait time, adding extra waits (although running slower than what the machine is capable of is not a desirable solution).
- Create and process a queue of frames.
- Two levels of nested `requestAnimationFrame`s.
- Log the timing of events (captured, drawn frame number n., etc.) which goes in nice order in the console. Never is more than one frame in the "queue".
- Drawing the results in a separate RAF.

Note, that this may be a bug with Safari itself, since I’ve seen this phenomenon on other sites (Coursera video player, to be specific), but I’m still interested in a workaround nonetheless.

Thanks.

Comment: option A would be the way to go. No requestAnimationFrame won't get mangled, apart from exception thrown during the execution, your whole function will get executed, and requestAnimationFrame will schedule a new execution for next painting event loop. Triple check that `longCalculation` does return a Promise that gets resolved when everything is ready. From here it sounds like it is throwing somewhere.

Comment: I wonder if some frames are completing their analysis before previous frames, causing them to be rendered, but when the previous frame renders, that's drawn too causing the frames to render out of order. Maybe try implementing debouncing of RAF? I'm particularly thinking of Paul Irish's 'Ticking' concept from https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/

Comment: I follow Option B from FaceAPI.js and get A LOT of issues when I clearTimeout() I wondering if you find an answer ?

Comment: I am also having this problem, exactly!  On older Safari..  @Matt, did you ever find any sort of solution or insight into this?